# SQL server select values from several JSON column

Tags: json, sql-server

I would like to retrieve values from JSON column.
There are my data :

[image]

I try to get firstName, lastName, "home" and "work" from shippingAddress JSON column.
So I use this query :

> SELECT  id, lastName, firstName, homeAddress, workAddress 
>   FROM dbo.person
>   CROSS  APPLY OPENJSON (shippingAddress ,'$')      WITH (
>         homeAddress nvarchar(4000) '$.home',        workAddress nvarchar(4000)
>   '$.work'  )

And the result is :

[image]

but I would like to have this result :

[image]

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution :

> SELECT    lastName,       firstName,          homeAddress =
>   JSON_VALUE(shippingAddress, '$[0].home'),         workAddress =
>   JSON_VALUE(shippingAddress, '$[1].work') FROM dbo.person pp